# как в tablayout программно сделать вкладку активной?

Tags: android, android-studio

как в tablayout программно сделать вкладку активной?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void selectPage(int pageIndex){
    tabLayout.setScrollPosition(pageIndex,0f,true);
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(pageIndex);
}
```

вызвать соответственно следующим образом, где 2 индекс страницы

```
selectPage(2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно зная индекс таба попробовать [вот так](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30944654/5330439)

```
TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
TabLayout.Tab tab = tabLayout.getTabAt(someIndex);
tab.select();
```

[Узнать](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38094050/5330439) текущий индекс таба

```
 tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            int position = tab.getPosition();
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        }
    });
```